# Target only the div directly after a div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I would like to target a div directly after a div in jQuery.

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<!-- 1 -->
<div class="title">
    <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<!-- 2 -->
<div class="title">
    <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<!-- 3 -->
<div class="title">
    <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

So from the above code, I would like the logic to go something like this:

"When a user clicks a div with class 'title' the closest 'boxes' div will slide toggle down, while no other divs are affected"

Here is the jQuery code I have so far:

```
jQuery(".title").click(function(){
    jQuery(".boxes").slideToggle();
});
```

This works, but of course when you click on 'title' all instances of 'boxes' slide toggle.

Note: I cannot change the classes or add classes to the divs because these are auto generated by wordpress

Any one know the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(this).next().slideToggle()`

Comment: oh my gosh wow that was such an easy fix. thank you! if you want rep points put that as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use .find()

```
$(".title").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".boxes").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! this may work but i already solved my question with Barmars answer he posted in the comments. I gave you an upvote for your answer though